# Connected component initial render fails because Redux state is not yet populated from server

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I am using Redux thunk and axios to make server calls and modify the state depending on the result.

The problem is that when I use a connected component, and its initial state depends on data from the server, it does not render (the connected props are empty)

```
render () (<div>{this.props.someData}</data>) // empty, or error, if nested

...

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  someData: state.someData
})
```

I also tried this:

```
componentWillMount = () => {
  this.setState({
    someData: this.props.someData
  })
}
```

And used `state` in `render`, but it didn't help.

Is there a way to wait for the server response before rendering or some other solution?

Comment: Where are you making the request for the data?

Comment: Hi, there some mistakes at you're code, Could you add the whole component.

Comment: @Geraint the component is nested a few levels seep inside a router and once I have the route params I call for the corresponding data

Answer (score 0):

You can conditionally render that part. Use a property to indicate fetching status (property name is `loading` in my example).

```
class UserDetails extends React.Component {
    state = {
        loading: true,
        data: null
    }

    fetch() {
        this.setState({
            loading: true
        })

        // an axios call in your case
        setTimeout(() => this.setState({
            loading: false,
            data: {
                nestedValue: 'nested value'
            }
        }), 500)
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.fetch()
    }

    render() {
        return <div>
            {this.state.loading ? <span>loading...</span> : <div>nested prop value: {this.state.data.nestedValue}</div>}
        </div>
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Typically you would use the Component.defaultProps object to initialize your props. So in your case, something like this will set your `someData` prop to an initial value before axios receives the data.

```js
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  // ... your implementation
}

MyComponent.defaultProps = {
    someData: [] // empty array or whatever the data type is
};
```

Edit: [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html#default-prop-values)

Comment: I don't think the OP wants to render an empty component and then update it later, but rather to wait, perhaps display a loading component while the data is still being fetched, hence your solution isn't necessarily solving the problem.

Comment: He did say "... or some other solution". This is typically the way to stop your component from not rendering when data isn't received. There's nothing stopping you from writing some `if (!someData) loading else render` logic in the component.